# How to pickle dump tfidf vectorizer with custom method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I have a tfidf tokenizer with custom analyzer,

```
def ngrams(text, n=3):
    text = str(text)
    text = text.lower()

    text = ' '+ text +' '
    ngrams = zip(*[text[i:] for i in range(n)])
    return [''.join(ngram) for ngram in ngrams]

# fit and transform 
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, analyzer=ngrams)
input_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(data)

print(input_matrix.shape)
```

I want to dump this and load it later on but not able to do so because of the custom method called ngrams which I use as a analyzer in tfidf.

When I do pickle.dump and then load, here is the error I get,

```
pickle.dump(vectorizer, open("data", "wb))
vec = pickle.load(open("data", "wb"))
```

> AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'ngrams' on <module '**main**'>

Does anyone know how to pickle dump tfidf along with the custom method. So I could just use pickle.load for loading.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use the [`dill`](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill) package which extends Python's `pickle` module:

> `dill` is quite flexible, and allows arbitrary user defined classes and functions to be serialized.

All you have to do would be to add the following import statement before pickling:

```py
import dill as pickle
```

Then you can go ahead as usual:

```py
pickle.dump(vectorizer, open("data", "wb"))
...
```

And it worked well for me when I loaded the vectorizer in another module in a different Python session:

```py
vec = pickle.load(open("data", "rb")) # <-- here it should be 'rb'
print(vec)

>>> TfidfVectorizer(analyzer=<function ngrams at 0x11f5f1440>)
```

Comment: @user_12 did this answer your question? If yes, please accept it and consider upvoting. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)